# Slope of the Bending moment diagram where a point force acts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, stresses, beam

Consider a beam that is arbitrarily loaded and at any distance x, we take an element in the beam between two sections, where a point force acts as shown.

[image]

Let us assume the directions of shear force and bending moment to be as shown in the figure.

Applying the equation of equilibrium we get,

$$V_1-P-V_2=0$$
$$V_2=V_1-P$$

Thus, $V_x=+V_1$ and $V_{x+dx}=+(V_1-P)$

---

*Note: Shear force which tries to rotate the element clockwise is taken as +ve and Bending moment which tends to compress the upper part of the beam is taken as positive.*

---

**We conclude that the shear force abruptly changes as we go from left to right across the point force.**

Taking moment about a point on the right face of the element:

$$-M_1-V_1dx+Pdx/2+M_2=0$$

$$M_2=M_1+V_1dx-Pdx/2$$

Thus, $M_x=+M_1$ and $M_{x+dx}= +(M_1+V_1dx-Pdx/2)$

The change in the bending moment $M_2-M_1$ is differential, thus as we go from left to right across a point force the bending moment essentially remains constant.

### My trouble starts from here:

If I try determining the slope of the BMD at x,

$$\frac{dM}{dx}=\frac{M_{x+dx}-M_x}{dx}=\frac{+(M_1+V_1dx-Pdx/2)-+M_1}{dx}=V_1-P/2$$

However the book I'm referring to says that - "Even though the bending moment M does not change at a concentrated load, its rate of change dM/dx undergoes an abrupt change".

I don't get how the slope undergoes an abrupt change, as from the analysis the slope is turning out to be $$V_1-P/2$$ at x.

Answer (score 1):

Because (to my understanding your problem is more in the interpretation of derivatives rather structural mechanics) I will try to explain it in parallel example. Hopefully it will make sense.

---

Imagine a car accelerating with $a [m/s^2]$, and at some point in time t suddenly decelerating at $- a [m/s^2]$.

The acceleration in time t will abruplty change from positive to minus.

IF the velocity in time $t$ was $v_0$ then the velocity at time $t+\delta t$  ill be $v(t+\delta t) = v_0 - a \delta t$. So only a miniscule difference.

You can apply the same logic if you equate:

- shear force (V) with acceleration
- moment (M) with velocity
- x direction with time t

---

the derivative of velocity with respect to time is Acceleration .

$$ a = \frac{\delta V}{\delta t}$$

The derivative of bending moment with respect to distance x is the shear force.

$$ V = \frac{\delta M}{\delta x}$$

Comment: I looked into what you're saying and yes I feel there is a flaw in my math. I came up with something, let me know if it makes sense to you. I'm determining the derivative without knowing whether the BM function is differentiable at x. If I evaluate the derivative at $x^-$ and $x^+$ I will get $V1$ and $V1-P$ respectively. Since, derivative at $x, x^-,x^+$ is not equal thus the BM function is not differntiable at x.

Comment: @HarshitRajput to be honest a) I never really thought about it that way, b) I wouldn't  be able to express it precisely in mathematical terms, because I am not that good at mathematical definitions.  When I answered I was focusing on the physical interpretation of the discontinuity of the derivative.